# TeeChart OnMouseDown fires FormActivate on parent form after opening child form

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'm using TeeChart Standard v2016 32bit VCL in Delphi  10.4

OnMouseDown on chart opens new form:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

But after that FormActivate is called on parent form. I'm closing child form there.

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Close;
end;
```

Why is that event called and how to resolve that?
In older version, Delphi 7 it was ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FChartOpened := TRUE;
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FChartOpened then
     FChartOpened := FALSE
  else
     Form2.Close;
end;
```